# Incorrect path from URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier (iCloud)

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion, icloud

I use an external hard drive for my user data, and 2 weeks ago I had a crash and changed to a new disc with another name. I do this on User & Groups advance options on the preferences panel.
My problem comes when I get the path from NSFileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier  it referes to the old external volume "jose" that I no longer have. How can I update it?

file://localhost/Volumes/Jose/Library/Mobile%20Documents/4C224W52W5~com~piso13~Recipes

Comment: is this still an issue for you or has `URLForUbiquityContainerIdenfier` finally updated for the new path?

Comment: still an issue... I've tried signing out of iCloud and back again. I even created a new user account, but since I assign the home directory to my external hard drive, I believe it is hard coded in some file in my disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i resolve the same probleme...

There is not posibility to reconfigure, now you must remove the current configuration.

Switch off iCloud "mobile documents" system preference... and remove the folder "˜/Library/Application Support/Ubiquity".

I don't know if it is necesary reboot, i do it.

Now... switch on "mobile documents" icloud system preference.

(sorry for my english)

Comment: That did it!, how did you found out about that ubiquity folder? Apple support just asked me to file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I this not something you can talk to the apple genius people about? A friend of mine had a similar issue and they were able to resolve it.

Comment: Yes thank you, I even payed for technical support but it seams there are extremely busy, it's been more a than a week without any response from Apple

Comment: Take it into a store they always deal with complaints there as they dont like a fuss to be made.